# Verificar o retorno boolean de função php em java

Tags: php, java

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em java que requer uma **licença** para ser ativada.
Já fiz a função em php que verifica os dados no banco de dados e retorna um true se tudo estiver certo, ou false se der errado.

Essa função está em uma url:

http://site.com.br/verificarlicenca

O que eu pensei é na aplicação java enviar a licença via GET para essa url, que ficará assim:

http://site.com.br/verificarlicenca?licenca=KEY

A minha função está pegando essa key e tratando, verificando se é verdadeira e retornando uma boolean.

Resumindo, preciso enviar esse parâmetro e também receber o retorno, EM JAVA, é possível?

Comment: Esse retorno é de uma página que foi gerada a partir do resultado da função em PHP? Ou você quer ler a função PHP a partir do Java? Poderia colocar mais detalhes na pergunta?

Comment: Desculpe amigo, já atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Fiz um [esboço](https://gist.github.com/denisrudnei/78da93e0968a0c146c6e8b829ef95a92) de código para te dar um norte, não vou poder responder nesse final de semana, se ninguém responder até segunda eu elabora uma resposta

Comment: Não entendi a parte do while, qual a funcionalidade dele? Como consigo verificar o retorno boolean?

Comment: Você fez um webservice em PHP. Isso significa que o Java não precisa se preocupar em qual linguagem essa informação está sendo fornecida, apenas consumir o webservice. Tem várias perguntas disso aqui

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a mesma linha de raciocinio do @Denis Rudnei de Souza, você pode ler o conteudo retornado pelo servidor (pagina php) seguindo as instruções postadas no [github](https://gist.github.com/denisrudnei/78da93e0968a0c146c6e8b829ef95a92):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ReadLicence {

  public static String valida(String key) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8000/a.php?licenca=" + key);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    //armazena os caracteres recebidos através da rede
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;

    //readline() permite ler uma linha (\n ou \n\r) do que foi retornada
    //como resposta pelo servidor (a partir do que está em bufferreader)
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String chave = "123571113";
    //mensagem recebida do servidor true ou false
    String resultado = valida(chave);
    System.out.println(resultado);

    if(resultado.equals("true")){
      System.out.println("licença valida");
    }else {
      System.out.println("licença invalida");
    }
  }
}
```

Tomei a liberdade de adicionar alguns comentarios. Além do codigo postado por @Denis Rudnei de Souza, adicionei o tratamento (não chega a tanto) para manipular a reposta do servidor. No servidor criei um pequeno escript chamado a.php:

```
<?php
function valida_licenca($chave){
    if($chave == '123571113'){
        return 'true';
    }else{
        return 'false';
    }
  }

//a função licença retorna string pois caso fosse boolean 
//seria convertido para 0 ou 1
echo valida_licenca($_GET['licenca']);
```

Com isso imagino ser possivel solucionar o seu problema. Embora fosse melhor o servidor retornar o conteudo em json (se quiser procure como ler json em java com a biblioteca [gson](https://github.com/google/gson). Há um tutorial interessante [aqui](http://blog.globalcode.com.br/2012/02/json-facil-em-java-com-gson.html)).

Um equivalente do servidor (PHP) para trabalhar com json seria:

```
<?php
function valida_licenca($chave){
    if($chave == '123571113'){
        return json_encode(['ativado' => true]);
    }else{
        return json_encode(['ativado' => false]);
    }
}

echo valida_licenca($_GET['licenca']);
```

E as modificações em java seriam:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class ReadLicence {

  public static String valida(String key) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8000/a.php?licenca=" + key);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    //armazena os caracteres recebidos através da rede
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;

    //readline() permite ler uma linha (\n ou \n\r) do que foi retornada
    //como resposta pelo servidor (a partir do que está em bufferreader)
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String chave = "123571113";
    //mensagem recebida do servidor true ou false
    String resultado = valida(chave);
    System.out.println(resultado);

    //a biblioteca json permite transformar um objeto json 
    //em um objeto java
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    //nesse caso no json retornado tem esse formato:
    //{ativado: boolean}. O valor do campo ativado é colocado
    //no atributo da classe Licenca, que tem o mesmo nome
    Licenca licenca = gson.fromJson(resultado, Licenca.class);
    System.out.println(licenca.ativado);

    if(licenca.ativado){
      System.out.println("licença valida");
    }else {
      System.out.println("licença invalida");
    }
  }

  private class Licenca{
    public Boolean ativado = null;
  }
}
```

O mais complicado é adicionar a biblioteca gson ao classpath do seu ambiente de desenvolvimento. O jar pode ser baixado [aqui](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.8.2%7C) ou diretamente [aqui](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.2/gson-2.8.2.jar).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo, vou tentar aqui. Tem algum motivo específico do por que o retorno seria melhor em json?

Comment: Se você precisar retornar alguma informação além do boolean. Tipo `{ativado: true, expira:'11-11-2011'}`, seria mais facil acessar seguindo esse formato do que ter que fazer explit em uma string.

Comment: Em questão de segurança, qual o melhor jeito? Pois só preciso verificar a key mesmo.